# Change user's photo to base64-encoded image received via POST

Tags: plugin-development, user-profile

I'm trying to change a userphoto of a certain user to a base64-encoded imagestring that is supplied in a POST request. I already succeeded in uploading an actual asset that way, however, userphotos seem to be handled in a completely different fashion apparently. While this is supposed to change in Craft3, is there a proper way to achieve what I'm trying in Craft 2.x?

This is what I've come up with so far, it obviously does not work though.

```
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $posts = json_decode($postdata);

    $user = craft()->users->getUserById($posts->userid);
    if ($user == null){
        return array( "status" => "no user found for id ".$posts->userid );
    }

    $imageData = base64_decode($posts->image);
    $source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);

    craft()->users->saveUserPhoto($user->id."-".time().".jpg",$source, $user);
```

Not sure whats wrong really, or how I am supposed to properly achieve what I'm trying to do. I suspect the image file isn't handed over to `saveUserPhoto()` in the correct way due to the following error message,

> Argument 2 passed to Craft\UsersService::saveUserPhoto() must be an
>   instance of Craft\BaseImage, resource given

, but I could be completely wrong with that.

Any ideas?